# Typeof generic type results in error

Tags: enums, typescript

I am writing a function that gets the string value of an enum.

```
const getEnumValueToString = <T>(enumValue: T, _enum: typeof T): string => _enum[enumValue]
```

However I get an error: `Cannot find name T`

I saw https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/204 but enums do not have constructors so it does not work. I know I could just inline it or use `any` but I would like to know how to properly type this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function:

```
<T>(enumValue: T, _enum: typeof T): string => _enum[enumValue]
```

is fairly useless. This is becuase its easier to do `SomeEnum[SomeEnum.Member]`  instead of calling this function. TypeScript already understands the a numeric access on an enum results in a string e.g.:

```
enum Color {
    Red
}

let foo = Color[Color.Red]; // foo is inferred to be a string
```

Comment: I understand that. I would still like to know how to type the function.

Comment: You don't need a generic for that e.g. `const getEnumValueToString = (enumValue: number, _enum: {[key:number]:string}): string => _enum[enumValue]`

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I missed that.